# How to preserve xml configuration when redeploying using update?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, tomcat-manager

I'm using tomcat manager to deploy my war files. To update a war I use the following url:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=/example&war=file:/path/example.war&update=true
```

The problem is that using this, the xml with the configuration (under Catalina/localhost/example.xml), is erased.

How can I preserve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your configuration in your webapp's `META-INF/context.xml` and tomcat will take care of the rest.

Comment: I did not know that option, but it is no feasible, cause I use the same war in different servers, which need diferent configuration.

Comment: If your build process supports it you can have many context.xml for the many target servers. Another option is to place the context.xml declarations statically inside the server.xml. I highly suggest trying out the first option though.

Comment: That was not what I was expecting, but I suppose that there is no other way. Thanks!

Comment: In my opinion, the usuall use case of updating a war, is deploy it and mantain the configuration that was created before. I don't see why the xml is erased.
In my particular case I can't use the context.xml because I need to share war between servers. So the only solution I see is using server.xml, but I think that using the single xml is quite more clean.